# Bookmarklet to take current url as a parameter to other URL

Tags: firefox, browser, javascript, url, bookmarklet

I want to make a bookmarklet that takes a string from current URL of the browser and passes it as parameter of my specific URL and reload this new URL in browser. The string required is after "=" sign in old URL.

Example:

Current Website URL:

```
http://www.someURL.com/?abc=thisString
```

After clicking bookmarklet, the new URL should be like:

```
http://www.newURLTakingParameter.com/abc?q=thisString
```

I have gone through Google about it but could not find exact solution to this. 
Anyone helping will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved it!

I used this JavaScript method to get search string from URL and then to remove question mark and equal sign etc from search string i used substring() method of javascipt and problem is solved.

Final Bookmarklet is:

```
javascript:location='www.newURLTakingParameter.com/abc?q='+window.location.search.substring(3,14)
```